# How to access node attribute through call-template

Tags: xslt-1.0

When I execute a call template, how do I access the attribute of the b node?  There are a lot of possible attributes I have to be able to access, is the only way to pass it as a parameter?

XML:

```
<a>
  <b id="anID"></b>
</a>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:call-tempalte name="renderB"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="renderB">
  <!-- Based on id of b, do something -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `<xsl:template name="renderB">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
</xsl:template>`
?

Comment: @id is accessible from within the renderB template?

Comment: yes - the context node does not change when you invoke `<xsl:call-template>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:call-template` does not change the context. If you called the template from the context of `<xsl:template match="b">`, then you are still in the context of `b` and the attributes of `b` are accessible simply as `@id`.